# Bishul akum on a dish whose ingredients are all eaten raw

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bishul-akum

Suppose you have a dish where each of its ingredients is commonly eaten raw, but the dish itself, when all ingredients are combined, is not eaten raw, and indeed would also be found on a king's table. Is there a prohibition of *bishul akum* on such a dish?

An example would be *palak paneer*, a curry commonly made of spinach, peppers, tomatoes, cheese, onions, and spices. Can a non-Jew cook *palak paneer* for a Jew in otherwise kosher kitchenware?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mark and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed when the majority of ingredients in a dish can be eaten raw, the food is exempt from *bishul akum*

OU Kosher gives the details [here](https://oukosher.org/publications/rov-tashmisho/)

> Shulchan Aruch (Y.D. 113:2) says that if a non-Jew cooked a mixture
> that contained some ingredients that can be eaten raw and some
> ingredients that require cooking, one needs to determine which
> ingredients are the ikar [main] and which are tafel [subsidiary].
>
> **If the ikar ingredients
> can be eaten raw then the food as a whole is viewed as edible raw and
> is exempt from bishul akum.** If however, the ikar ingredients require
> cooking, then this food requires bishul Yisroel. If none of the
> ingredients are clearly the ikar ingredients, then we follow the rov
> (majority).

**Note however** that vegetables require checking for bugs, which is a very significant prohibition, and some ingredients you mention (specifically cheese) require kosher supervision. Last, cooking with onions creates additional complexity in case one mixes milk and meat utensils. **As such, one needs to be extremely careful should this situation occur in practice.**

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).